# How to make an executable jar file from Maven with no Main Class

Tags: maven, docker, jar

I'm using Maven to build a simple web service, without a usual main class with a main method.

Maven builds a war file and it's executed as its supposed to, however I would like to make an executable jar file instead. I have found a lot of examples of a jar plugin for this, but for those you need to specify a main class, and none of the classes in my project are accepted as such.

The reason that I want to build a jar file is that I want to build and run an image with Docker. I haven't found an example yet to run the war file with Docker, but if someone has a solution for that, it would also solve the problem.

I've tried this with Docker swarm but couldn't make that work either.

Here's the projects pom file

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProductMicroService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProductMicroService</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>ProductMicroService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!--uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>0.99</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: I am no docker expert, but to run a war, you usually need a container (like Tomcat, Wildfly,...). To build a web service as a jar, you can use Spring boot. If your jar has no main class, there is no point in running it.

Comment: @JFMeier I'm not sure if I get your answer correctly, but what I'm trying to achieve is something like this: https://github.com/yamad/jaxrs-docker-example - a Maven project with no main class, that builds a jar file and runs it. But when trying to implement this in my project, that uses a glassfish server, I run in to other problems.

Comment: Your example project from github uses wildfly swarm, which bundles a wildfly into the jar. So technically, the jar has a main class which is supplied by wildfly swarm. This main class starts the wildfly and and your application inside the wildfly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation @JFMeier, I'm proceeding by looking over that example again.

Comment: You cannot make an executable jar without having main class. Whether it's Wilfdly, Tomcat, Jetty, or whatever, they all have some sort of main class starting the respective app. What exactly will you otherwise be starting? Nothing?